# I have a error when starting my discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('new role')
async def role(ctx, member: discord.Member=None,role_time : int, role: discord.Role = None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Who do you want me to give a role?")
        return
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="muted")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("Ok, I did it :thumpsup:")
    if role is None:
       return await self.bot.say('Pls write a role')

    await asyncio.sleep(role_time)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("The time of the role of {} is up".format(member))
```

this dos end me this:

```
async def role(role_time : int, role: discord.Role = None, ctx, member: discord.Member=None,):<br/>
                   ^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

(the ^ is on the ctx

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Non-default arguments must come before default arguments. Change function definition to :

```
async def role(ctx, role_time : int, member: discord.Member=None, role: discord.Role = None):
```

You'll also have to modify function call accordingly.

Comment: now he says this:@bot.command()
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined

Comment: @vinyzulöl Did you import it? Anyway, that’s a completely unrelated error, make a new question for it if you need help solving that.

Comment: only can comment 90 minutes. what do i have to import lol?

Comment: You're going to have to initialize your bot. You need to
```import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "PREFIX-HERE")```

Be sure to insert your desired prefix.